# How to perform #find on an object without Active Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

Here's what's happend: I have gone and pulled a large amount of data from an API. This is nice, but it includes a lot of results.

When I do a `result.find(id: api_id)` I get all the results like find was never performed. `#where` does not work either. I'm assuming this is because its not extending from Active Model.

**Key Question**: How do I find, say, the name of a particular object in an active resource collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.find(id: api_id)` in active resource is essentially doing an api request as in (uri_of_api)/objects/:api_id)

But the :find method on an array is a different aninmal.  You can look up the array 'find' method here... http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find

The correct format would be...

```
result.find{|rec| rec.id == api_id}
```